# Не работает стиль (CSS) на моем сайте

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Я пишу проект и хочу добавить стиль чтобы все было ровно (шаблон меню) но почему то он не читает CSS файл и папку images
Остальные стили читает кроме стиля "styleadmin.css"

Хочу чтобы на странице читал css файл "styleadmin.css" и папку images

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

AdminDecorator.jsp

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleadmin.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/js-func.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<div id="header">
    <div class="shell">
        <h1 id="logo" class="notext"><a href="#">Plain Plan - Keep youy website simple</a></h1>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" class="active">Главная страница</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cтуденты</a>
                    <div class="dd-holder">
                        <div class="dd-t"></div>
                        <div class="dd">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allStudents">Список студентов</a></li>
                                                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('USER')">
                                                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent">Добавить студента</a></li>
                                                    </sec:authorize>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dd-b"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                            <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Войти</a></li>

                            <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()"> 
                <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Выйти</a></li>
               </sec:authorize>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>



        <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/template/admintemplate.jsp"/>  
    </body>
</html>
```

allStudentsAdmin.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/styleadmin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/styleadmin.css"%></style>
        <title>Все студенты</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="it">
                <h3 style="color:greenyellow" >Список всех студентов</h3>
                ${message}

                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col"># </font></th>
                            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Name </font></th>

                            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Surname </font></th>
                            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Avatar </font></th>
                            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Edit </font></th>
                            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Delete </font></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                            <tr>
                                 <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#fff"  scope="row">1 </font></th>
                                 <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#fff">${student.name}</font></td>
                                 <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#fff">${student.surname}</font></td>

                                <td bgcolor="#000000">
                                    <c:if test="${empty student.avatar}">
                                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/768px-No_image_available.svg.png"
                                             style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                                    </c:if>
                                    <c:if test="${not empty student.avatar}">
                                        <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}"
                                             style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                                    </c:if>
                                </td>

                                <td bgcolor="#000000">
                                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editStudent/${student.id}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td bgcolor="#000000">
                                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/deleteStudent/${student.id}">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

мой styleadmin.css

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline:0; }

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    background: #fff url(images/bg.gif) repeat-x 0 106px;
}

a { color: #0252aa; text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
a img { border: 0; }

input, textarea, select { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
textarea { overflow: auto; }

.cl { display: block; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; clear: both; }
.notext { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }

.left, .alignleft { float: left; display: inline; }
.right, .alignright { float: right; display: inline; }

.shell { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }

.last { margin-right: 0 !important; }

#header { position: relative; height: 106px; background: url(images/header-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; margin-bottom: 26px; z-index: 5;  }

h1#logo { float: left; display: inline; width: 210px; height: 56px; margin: 23px 0 0 12px; }
h1#logo a { display: block; height: 56px; background: url(images/logo.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }

#navigation { position: relative; float: right; display: inline; margin-top: 32px; z-index: 5; }
#navigation ul { list-style: none outside none; }
#navigation ul li { position: relative; float: left; display: inline; margin-right: 10px; }
#navigation ul li a { width: 84px; height: 44px; display: block; color: #474747; font-size: 13px; text-align: center; line-height: 43px; padding-right: 2px; }
#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li a.active,
#navigation ul li a.hover { background: url(images/nav-hover.gif) no-repeat 0 0; text-decoration: none; z-index: 1; }
#navigation ul li .dd-holder { position: absolute; top: 33px; left: 0; display: none; width: 152px; height: 100%; z-index: 5; }
#navigation ul li .dd { background: url(images/dd-bg.png) repeat-y 0 0; }
#navigation ul li .dd-t { width: 152px; height: 7px;  background: url(images/dd-t.gif) no-repeat 0 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
#navigation ul li .dd-b { position: relative; width: 152px; height: 9px; background: url(images/dd-b.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
#navigation ul li .dd ul { padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 17px; }
#navigation ul li .dd ul li { float: none; display: block; height: 12px; padding-bottom: 10px; background: url(images/pink-arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 4px;  padding-left: 10px; margin: 0; }
#navigation ul li .dd ul li a { height: 12px; font-size: 11px; line-height: 12px; width: auto; height: auto; height: 100%; color: #6c6c6c; text-align: left; }
#navigation ul li .dd ul li a:hover { background: none; color: #c40083; }

#slider { position: relative; z-index: 1;  height: 225px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
#slider .shell { position: relative; height: 225px; }

.slider-left { float: left; display: inline; width: 284px; height: 207px; background: url(images/slider-left-bg.gif) no-repeat 0 0; color: #fff;  padding: 18px 20px 0 20px; }
.slider-left h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 13px; }
.slider-left p { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial; }
.slider-left .order-now { display: block; width: 134px; height: 38px; background: url(images/ordernow.gif) no-repeat 0 0; font-size: 16px; color: #fff; line-height: 37px; text-align: center; margin: 41px 0 0 69px; }
.slider-left .order-now:hover { background-position: 0 bottom; text-decoration: none; }
.slider-right { position: relative; float: left; display: inline; width: 656px; height: 225px; }
.slider-content { position: relative; width: 656px; height: 225px; overflow: hidden;  }
.slider-content ul { list-style: none outside none; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.slider-content ul li,
.jcarousel-clip { position: relative; width: 656px; height: 225px; z-index: 1; }

.slider-nav { position: absolute; bottom: 14px; right: 19px; display: block; z-index: 10; }
.slider-nav ul { list-style: none outside none; }
.slider-nav ul li { float: left; display: inline; width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-right: 4px; }
.slider-nav ul li a { width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; background: url(images/slider-nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
.slider-nav ul li a:hover,
.slider-nav ul li a.active { background: url(images/slider-nav-hover.png) no-repeat 0 0; }

#main { }
#main h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #4c4c4c; }

#sidebar { float: left; display: inline; width: 324px; }
#sidebar .text-container { min-height: 221px; background: #eaebeb url(images/text-containerbg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; padding: 20px 15px 0 18px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
#sidebar .text-container h2 { margin-bottom: 6px; }

.post { }
.post h2 { border-bottom: 5px solid #e4e4e4; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 11px; }
.post .more { display: block; background: url(images/pink-arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 4px; color: #c40083; font-size: 11px; line-height: 12px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; }
.post .more:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
#sidebar .post { padding: 0 18px 0 14px; }
#sidebar .post .more { margin-top: 17px; }

#content { float: right; display: inline; width: 600px; padding-top: 17px; margin-right: 10px;}

.col { margin-bottom: 25px; }
.cols-2 { float: left; display: inline; width: 280px; margin-right: 40px; }

#footer { height: 87px; background: url(images/footer-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; font-size: 11px; color: #7f7f7f; }
#footer .shell { padding: 26px 0 0 0; }
#footer a { color: #7f7f7f; }
#footer p.left span { padding: 0 3px; }





#sidebar .text-container { height: 221px; }
.slider-nav ul li a  { background-image: none; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/slider-nav.png', sizingMethod='image');}
.slider-nav ul li a:hover,
.slider-nav ul li a.active  { background-image: none; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/slider-nav-hover.png', sizingMethod='image');}
```

Comment: `/` добавьте перед `css/styleadmin.css`, перед путем `images/..` аналогично

Comment: Я добавил но все так же криво вообще стиля нету

Comment: в консоли браузера есть ошибки?

Comment: styleadmin.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery-1.4.2.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.jcarousel.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
js-func.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
styleadmin.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: @СтивГейтс а теперь перед `/` в начале добавь еще `..`

Comment: блин так же все((((

Comment: @СтивГейтс https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files#Файловые_пути

Answer (score 0):

а какой полный путь? файл html и папка css лежат в одной папке? в файле styleadmin.css нужно выйти на уровень наверх, чтобы зайти в images `background: #fff url(../images/bg.gif) repeat-x 0 106px;`